# How do I delete an item when I have a chest open?

Tags: stardew-valley

When I click on an item in my inventory while I have a chest open, the item teleports into the chest instead of letting me pick it up!  I can't delete any items because they just jump back and forth between my backpack and the chest!  How do I delete these items to make room for more?

Comment: what was the question?

Comment: Your post certainly implies you're asking how to delete items while you have a chest inventory open, so I'm going to edit it to reflect that.  If I'm wrong, you can rollback my edit by clicking [here](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/posts/272139/revisions) and choosing rollback, or better, you can edit it yourself using the edit button under the tag to make it more clear exactly what question you want answered.

Answer (score 2):

Move the items you want to delete to your inventory, close the chest screen, open your inventory normally, trash the items, then open the chest again to pull more stuff out.  Repeat if necessary to make more room.

If the chest is full when you click an item in your backpack (or if your backpack is full when you click an item in the chest), the item will "stick" to your cursor instead of jumping, so you can trash them without closing the chest window in that case.